# Discordpy banlist with pagination

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to do a banlist with pagination, I already have the part that send the banlist but I'm having trouble finding how to paginate something in Discordpy, here is the code if it's needed:

```
#COMMAND banlist
@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='banlist', description='List all baned users')
@commands.has_role(Staff_role)
async def banlogs(self,ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    bans = await guild.bans()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Ban Logs", colour=discord.Color.red())
    for ban in bans:
        embed.add_field(name=f"Name: ", value=f"{ban.user}")
        embed.add_field(name="Is_bot?", value=f"{ban.user.bot}")
        embed.add_field(name="Reason: ", value=f"{ban.reason}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Is it possible to make that if the message has more that 10 users, create another page?

Comment: You can split `bans` list in two or more lists basing on `len()` and then make an embed for each of them. I do that often when I get into character limit in embeds. Then I skip the title in the second list and it looks just like it was one.

Comment: Yes, `bans[:10]`. Or you could add a page number argument to find which slice of the bans to get (or use buttons to navigate it).

Comment: @EricJin Where do i have to put `bans[:10]`?

Comment: `for ban in bans[:10]` will show the first 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rapptz](https://github.com/rapptz), The owner of [discord.py](https://github.com/rapptz/discord.py) has created a module for helping with pagination, named `discord-ext-menus`.

#### To install:

```bash
$ python -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/rapptz/discord-ext-menus
```

#### Useful things

[Source](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus)